# All Unique Permutations

Tags: mathematics, wordplay

We have the word: RAPSEVNOBLURKANIWA

We want to find the number of unique permutations that could be made with RAP always staying together, so that there are:

> **no 3 adjacent consonants**,
>
> **no 2 adjacent vowels** and

**for every odd pair of adjacent consonants, the first letter is alphabetically smaller than the second**, while
**for every even pair - the opposite (the first letter is alphabetically bigger than the second)**.

> ***example***: in the given word: **(1-odd)-P is smaller than S**, *(2-even)-V is bigger than N*, **(3-odd)-B is smaller than L**, *(4-odd)-R is bigger than K*

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question as [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81626/arrange-stakexchangepuzzling) but more difficult? Why, when you didn't accept any answer and it was put on hold? You haven't given any helpful feedback to answers in the last one.

Comment: Last one was disliked as it was too hard so I made it a bit easier and more understandable

Comment: Last one had to be a fixed pattern of vowel and consonant, this has more arrangements of vowel/consonant. The last one wasn't put on hold because it was too hard, but because "This question is off-topic as it appears to be a mathematics problem, as opposed to a mathematical puzzle." I am not going to spend time on this problem, when it might be put on hold before I get there.

Comment: So you wanna say you solve problems for others and not for yourself?

Comment: I am saying that a solution cannot be posted once the question is put on hold.

Comment: If it gets put on hold, you will atleast have had a good exercise :P

Comment: @WeatherVane You're probably right that it looks more like a problem rather that a puzzle, but the OP is right that it's a good exercise, so the question probably does not deserve downvoting.

Comment: @trolley813 I did not downvote, and despite my comments submitted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer (after the no-computer tag was removed) is

> $4419100800$ unique solutions.
>
>  Unlike OP's [previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81626/arrange-stakexchangepuzzling) there are $132$ valid permutations of vowel/consonant.
>  Placing **RAP** over each single-vowel position (except at the ends) gave me $842$ templates.
>  Removing **RAP** from **RAPSEVNOBLURKANIWA** leaves 6 vowels and 9 consonants.
>
>  The number of ways to arrange the remaining 6 vowels, with 1 duplicate **A**, is
>  $ \frac{6!}{2!} = 360$
>
>  For each template, I recursively permuted the 9 consonants to comply with the rules.
>  After removing any duplicates there were $12275280$ solutions.
>
>  $12275280 \times 360 = 4419100800$ solutions, one of which is **RAPSEVNOBLURKANIWA**.

Answer (score 1):

So far (partial answer):

> 1. Since the **RAP** must always stand together, we can consider it as a single "letter" (a consonant).
>  2. So, now we have 16 letters, 10 consonants and 6 vowels. Let's substitute each consonant by 0 and each vowel by 1, and find all valid zero-one patterns.
>  3. We need to find number of permutations of 10 zeroes and 6 ones without 2 ones or 3 zeroes standing together. Each permutation is uniquely determined by the numbers of zeroes between adjacent ones (number of zeroes before 1st one, then between 1st and 2nd, etc.). Since there are 6 ones, there are 7 numbers which can be either 1 or 2 (since 0 would result into 2 ones standing together, and 3 or more will result into 3 zeroes standing together), however the 1st and last (7th) number can be zero. These numbers will sum up to 10 (since there are 10 zeroes in total), so *there are either exactly 4 ones and 3 twos, or 1 zero, 2 ones and 4 twos, or 2 zeroes and 5 twos* in these 7 numbers (since 1+1+1+1+2+2+2=0+1+1+2+2+2+2=0+0+2+2+2+2+2=10). The number of permutations with no zeroes will be exactly **7C3=7*6*5/(1*2*3)=35**, with 1 zero will be **2*6C2=2*6*5/(1*2)=30** (since the zero can be either first or last), and with two zeroes **1** (only one: 0222220). Total number of ways is **35+30+1=66**. 
>  4. The vowels can be in any order, so there are **6!=720** ways to arrange them.
>  5. Now assign a digit 0 to 9 to each of the consonants according to their alphabetical order (here we can treat RAP as just P, since there are no letters between P and R (Qs are not present in the set)), and find number of valid permutations of 0123456789 for the all 66 cases.
>  6. Actually, the 66 cases can be reduced to 3 ones (with 3, 4 and 5 consonant pairs) since we can build a one-to-one correspondence between permutations for the cases having the same number of consonant pairs, so the number of valid sequences will remain the same.
>  7. So, the following 3 case classes are: find a permutation *abcdefghij* of 0123456789, where (1) a<b, c>d and e<f (35 cases);  (2) the same as (1) and also g>h (30 cases); (3) the same as (2) and also i<j (1 case).
>  8. (*Here I may be wrong*) It's intuitively clear that the part of valid sequences will be **1/8**, **1/16** and **1/32** of the total number of permutations (which is **10!=3628800**), or **453600**, **226800**, and **113400** for the case classes (1), (2), and (3) respectively (since in each pair of digits, the first is either less or greater than the second, and this seems to be equally probable, but I cannot prove it) .
>  9. So, the final answer is **720*(35*453600+30*226800+1*113400)=16411248000**

*Edit:* Tried to complete the answer, but step 8 may be incorrect.

Comment: That's the hardest one :D

Comment: @Kradecnakysmet Tried to complete it by myself.

Comment: There is R that's not part of RAP

Comment: Yes, but we can treat it as being alphabetically after the RAP.

Comment: if 2nd R is before RAP it doesn't count as valid